# Installing lynx without apt-get

Tags: linux, lynx

We have a small gateway running linux which is built without apt-get.  We need to connect it to a local wifi network which uses a public Web interface and want to use lynx to set up the connection.  We can download lynx on a separate machine and `scp` it over to the gateway, but all the lynx instructions I have seen require using `apt-get` for installation.  Has anyone had experience installing lynx withOUT apt-get?

Comment: If you have down-loaded the `.deb` flle, you can install it with `gdebi`.

Comment: Alas, `gdebi` is not built-in either.  I dont believe any package installers were built in.

Comment: If you have a Live Boot disc for the target, you may be able to copy the files you need from there. I once did something like this with `chroot`, but I can't recall the procedure and it may not be something you can use. But it depends on having or obtaining a Live Boot for the target OS with the same release and architecture, and being able to run it.

Comment: You can also use `dpkg -i ...` to install `deb` files. And it's difficult to guess for us *what* programs are available on your small gateway ... how did you set up that gateway in the first place? Whatever you used for that will probably also work to install extra packages.